# Error al cerrar cursor de select con SQLite y cambiar de fragments

Tags: android, sqlite, select, fragment, cursor

Tengo un problema difícil de explicar y del que *puedo poner código si lo deseáis* pero **creo que es mejor comentarlo como pueda y que me déis opinión.**
Tengo una aplicación android que funciona con varias activities, pero que contiene una principal y en ella hago **cambio de fragments para navegar**...
Un fragmento menú que conecta con una interfaz para pasar un numero (este número lo pasa a la activity y hace el cambio a x fragmento) ... **Menú con botones a la izquierda y fragmento dinámico a la derecha.**
Vale, la app está ya terminada pero he encontrado un error que tiene que ver al **cambiar de fragments y cerrar cursores**... Es en un fragment en específico donde uso un **listview personalizado para cargar contenido de una base de datos sqlite interna.** 
Hago selects, por lo tanto abro cursores, y los cierro.. Todo perfecto.
Pero tengo **otro fragmento con un recyclerview *que tarda en cargar un poco porque es como una galería con miniaturas de fotos.*
**Estos dos fragmentos son los conflictos.** *En el segundo no abro cursores.*
Pues bien, cuando abro el listview y vuelvo al recyclerview, cuando hago esto dos veces, **me echa de la aplicación(y vuelve a entrar)** y tira el típico error de que te dejas un cursor por cerrar.

```
05-23 16:47:27.112 20877-20886/com.example.practicas_.arcadiatruck E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
    at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180)
```

La cuestión es que cuando entro en el fragmento del listview, abro, y **no puedo cerrar el cursor hasta que hago algo**, o bien entrar en un elemento del listview(carga otra lista con mas info, y cierro el anterior cursor cuando hago click) o bien cambiar de fragmento y cuando cambio de fragmento utilizo la interfaz anteriormente mencionada, y antes de hacer cualquier transacción de fragmento se asegura de que *si está abierto este cursor, cerrarlo.*
Lo cierra en todos los demás fragmentos, pero en el recyclerview como tarda algo mas pues al final cuando pruebo varias veces, no ha cerrado correctamente y da el error.
**Probé a usar delay/handler** para cerrar el cursor antes de que se hiciera cualquier tipo de transacción de fragmento y nada. Estoy desesperado, es un error pequeño pero que al ser la app cliente conectada a servidor, hay veces que reinicia la app y no conecta bien al servidor. Bueno, en los casos que no conecta es porque no reinicia del todo, si no que crashea por así decirlo...

¿Se os ocurre algo que pueda hacer? 
Cierro siempre cursores, pero cuando hay este tipo de retraso entre estos dos fragments en específico pues al final acaba reseteando la app...

Para cerrar cuando pulso en un boton del menú y accedo a la interfaz, utilizo este código... **Lo pongo para que os hagáis una idea como lo hago, por si con variables estáticas da algún tipo de fallo o algo...** Dentro de mi clase de mi fragmento, utilizo el normal `cursor.close` ...

```
if (HistoricoIntervenciones.cursor != null) {
                    if (!HistoricoIntervenciones.cursor.isClosed()) {
                        HistoricoIntervenciones.cursor.close();

                    }
                }
```

Mil gracias de antemano.

**Actualizo 24/05/2018**
(Código de la clase donde abro el cursor; lo cierro también en otra parte que pongo debajo, fuera de la clase, en el menú cuando toco botones y salgo de ese fragment)

```
    import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HistoricoIntervenciones extends Fragment {

public DataBaseManager manager;
public static SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
Fragment fragmentInformacionHI;
public static Cursor cursor;


public HistoricoIntervenciones() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_historico_intervenciones, container, false);


    manager = new DataBaseManager(getContext());
    fragmentInformacionHI = new InfoHI();
    ListView lvData = view.findViewById(R.id.lvData);

    String[] from = new String[]{DataBaseManager.CN_FECHA, DataBaseManager.CN_EXP, DataBaseManager.CN_P, DataBaseManager.CN_DIRECCION, DataBaseManager.CN_POBLACION, DataBaseManager.CN_TIPOLOGIA, DataBaseManager.CN_DESCRIPCION, DataBaseManager.CN_FECHA2, DataBaseManager.CN_COORDENADAX, DataBaseManager.CN_COORDENADAY, DataBaseManager.CN_ALERTANTE, DataBaseManager.CN_TELEFONO, DataBaseManager.CN_PROVINCIA};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.fecha1, R.id.exp1, R.id.p1, R.id.direccion1, R.id.poblacion1, R.id.tipologia1, R.id.descripcion1, R.id.o_fecha2, R.id.o_coordenadax, R.id.o_coordenaday, R.id.o_alertante, R.id.o_telefono, R.id.o_provincia};

    cursor = manager.cargarCursor();
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.listview_item_row_lvhi, cursor, from, to, 0);


    lvData.setAdapter(adapter);


    lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            FragmentManager miManejador = getFragmentManager();

            TextView expediente = view.findViewById(R.id.exp1);
            TextView prioridad = view.findViewById(R.id.p1);
            TextView fecha = view.findViewById(R.id.o_fecha2);
            TextView tipologia = view.findViewById(R.id.tipologia1);
            TextView direccion = view.findViewById(R.id.direccion1);
            TextView poblacion = view.findViewById(R.id.poblacion1);
            TextView provincia = view.findViewById(R.id.o_provincia);
            TextView coordenadax = view.findViewById(R.id.o_coordenadax);
            TextView coordenaday = view.findViewById(R.id.o_coordenaday);
            TextView descripcion = view.findViewById(R.id.descripcion1);
            TextView alertante = view.findViewById(R.id.o_alertante);
            TextView telefono = view.findViewById(R.id.o_telefono);


            String info_expediente = expediente.getText().toString();
            String info_prioridad = prioridad.getText().toString();
            String info_fecha = fecha.getText().toString();
            String info_tipologia = tipologia.getText().toString();
            String info_direccion = direccion.getText().toString();
            String info_poblacion = poblacion.getText().toString();
            String info_provincia = provincia.getText().toString();
            String info_coordenadax = coordenadax.getText().toString();
            String info_coordenaday = coordenaday.getText().toString();
            String info_descripcion = descripcion.getText().toString();
            String info_alertante = alertante.getText().toString();
            String info_telefono = telefono.getText().toString();


            Bundle args = new Bundle();


            args.putString("expediente", info_expediente);
            args.putString("prioridad", info_prioridad);
            args.putString("fecha2", info_fecha);
            args.putString("tipologia", info_tipologia);
            args.putString("direccion", info_direccion);
            args.putString("poblacion", info_poblacion);
            args.putString("provincia", info_provincia);
            args.putString("coordenadax", info_coordenadax);
            args.putString("coordenaday", info_coordenaday);
            args.putString("descripcion", info_descripcion);
            args.putString("alertante", info_alertante);
            args.putString("telefono", info_telefono);

            fragmentInformacionHI.setArguments(args);


            FragmentTransaction miTransaccion = miManejador.beginTransaction();
            miTransaccion.replace(R.id.actividadfragments, fragmentInformacionHI);

            cursor.close();

            miTransaccion.commit();


        }
    });


    return view;


}


}
```

Aquí es donde cierro otra vez el cursor cuando salgo del fragment sin pulsar ningún elemento del listview.

```
public class Menu extends Fragment {

private final int[] BOTONESMENU = {R.id.botoninicio, R.id.botonhistoricointervenciones, R.id.botonarchivos, R.id.botonconfiguracion, R.id.boton_emergencia};


public Menu() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View mimenu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);


    Button botonmenu;
    for (int i = 0; i < BOTONESMENU.length; i++) {
        botonmenu = (Button) mimenu.findViewById(BOTONESMENU[i]);

        final int queBoton = i;

        botonmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (HistoricoIntervenciones.cursor != null) {
                    if (!HistoricoIntervenciones.cursor.isClosed()) {
                        HistoricoIntervenciones.cursor.close();

                    }
                }


                Activity estaActividad = getActivity();
                ((ComunicaMenu) estaActividad).menu(queBoton);
//Aquí le paso a la interfaz comunicamenu el boton que pulse, y con este botón inicia la transacción de fragmentos

            }

        });

    }
    return mimenu;
}

}
```

Comment: Ok, agrega por favor el método donde creas los cursores.

Comment: Mañana a primera hora lo pongo, que no lo tengo en casa

Comment: @Jorgesys actualicé mi pregunta con la información que me pediste! ^^

Comment: Solucionado, llevo toda la mañana con el error, era el strict mode lo que hacía que me fallara, lo quité (que lo tuve que añadir para probar unas cosas ) y listo, probé y todo perfecto ^^